# How to use a String constant in the ID declaration of an MXML component

Tags: apache-flex, constants, mxml, identifier

I was wondering, if you have multiple components files that uses the same child component (but with slightly modified parameters), is it possible to assign that child component an ID with a String Constant?

When I try the following in Flex SDK 3.5, it gives me a compile error:

```
<!-- Example -->
<mx:Button id="{ComponentIDs.ID_BUTTON_ONE}" />
```

Error:

```
"{ComponentIDs.ID_BUTTON_ONE}" is not a valid identifier.
```

Any guess if this is even possible to achieve? Does the syntax differ for ID fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components ids in MXML are evaluated at the compile time. So you cannot use any kind of expressions there.

Answer (score 1):

So this means that even for the state tag, in its shiney new spark version, neither can any form of String constants be employed in the mxml. So of course, the next train of developer thought is how to do it in ActionScript, and everything goes hunky-dory for creating states in code using Object notation, ... until you realise that the includeIn token is an mxml compiler thing and means nothing to ActionScript ... So there you are, you have to keep using String literals in your code